# how to block past dates in php and in input?

Tags: php, date, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-comparison

```
<input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="calendar" />
```

Here is my script:

```
 <script>

    $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
    });
    </script>
```

here php

```
if( $date < strtotime( date('m/d/Y', $time )) ) {
     echo "<script>alert('You can't put past day..'); </script>"; }
```

I want to block the users enter past date wrongly or as know..but it does not work..i cant block..how can i block users enter past dates? i want only users can enter today n next days..so i want to filter with input in php.

Comment: Where does `$time` come from? What is its value?

Comment: $time=$_POST['datepicker']; this is not problem..

Comment: Then it should be `if (strtotime(date('m/d/Y', $time )) < time())`

Comment: What format is the date and time going to be?

Comment: @JohnConde Since he doesn't have a `dateFormat` option, it defaults to `"mm/dd/yy"`

Comment: @Barmar it didnt work..

Comment: `strtotime( date('m/d/Y', $time )`? That is an UTTER waste of cpu cycles. take a timestamp, convert to string, then convert BACK to timestamp?

Comment: $time=time(); in my codes

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` doesn't take a format string, the function you want to use is [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It returns a `DateTime` object, not a timestamp, so you need to compare it with a `DateTime`:

```
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date) < new DateTime()) {
    echo "<script>alert('You can't put past day..'); </script>";
} else {
    // code to insert into database
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/rLXbOL)

Comment: can u block with the codes in ur test ? if u tested, can u show me ?

Comment: @Barmar I'm willing to bet that the core problem, could be inside code the OP isn't showing, *and a lot of it.*

Comment: @UmutBulut The `INSERT` should be inside the `else` clause, so you don't insert when the date is in the past.

Comment: What is the value of `$date`? Does it match the format string?

Comment: @Barmar They're no longer responding, because they posted their own answer, and I placed a comment under it also.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed n maybe it help any one who need like me..

```
<input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="calendar" /><br />


  <script>
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
});
</script>

$year=$_POST['year'];
$date=$_POST['datepicker'];
$timer=$_POST['timer'];

$time=time();


        $start_data = date('m/d/Y', time() - (86400));

    $now=date('m/d/Y', $time);


if(  $date  < $start_data ){
    echo "<script>alert('Failed..'); </script>";

    }
```

thanks for ur help again..

Comment: so, what's different here than what you posted for code, or did NOT post in your question? I can't see this Q&A being of any worth, not without knowing what the *real* problem was from the beginning. Something that I made a comment about under Barmar's answer, that there was code missing. Your question was unclear from the beginning, as is this answer.

Comment: This won't work. Dates in `m/d/Y` format can't be compared with `<` properly. For instance `"03/31/2015" < "06/30/2014"`

Comment: If you want to compare dates in string format, you should put them in `Y-m-d` format.

Comment: My guess is you tested this only with dates in the same year.

Comment: yep..i blocked other days...also i said @Fred at beginnig i want block past days..n i must put only date calculater..if u didnt get my problem, i cant do anything.also there wasnt any missing code..so that i tested other ways it worked..n thanks Barmar for ur help..u gave me good ideas to fix..good works ^_^